# Data from DB displays on webpage with html tags instead of formatted text

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, ckeditor

Node.js app with Express, MongoDB, Pug and CKEditor 4. The problem is: I try to submit data from editor into DB and after that display them on webpage. The data appears like plain text with html tags instead of formatted text as it looks in editor.

My question is: why data not display properly and how to solve this issue?

Image 1 - Formatting before submit

[image: Formatting before submit]

Image 2 - Data from DB on a webpage

[image: Rendered data from DB]

Webpage source:

```
&lt;li&gt;Article One&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Article One&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Article One&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ol&gt;
```

Code fragments:

1) article.pug

```
extends layout

block content
  h1.page-header= article.title
  h5 Written by #{author}
  p= article.body
```

2) add_article.pug

```
extends layout

block content
  h1.page-header #{title}
  form(method='POST' action='/articles/add')
    #form-group
      label Title:
      input.form-control(name='title' type='text')
    #form-group
      label Body:
      textarea.form-control(name='body' id='editor')
    br
    input.btn.btn-primary(type='submit' value='Submit')
```

3) main.js

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is escaped by default in Pug. You need to wrap content in `!{ }` to have it unescaped. See more info here: https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped

Note that rendering unescaped HTML can pose a security risk.

Comment: It works. But now I wonder is it possible to solve security risk issue?

Comment: You can sanitize user-submitted HTML. This will only allow some HTML tags to be rendered. So somebody won't be able to put in a malicious <script> tag. Here's a good npm module that will do it: https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html This will escape some HTML tags but leave tags like <ul> and <li> intact.